# KnockoutJS single page application tutorial step one ambiguity

Tags: knockout.js

I'm following KnocoutJS interactive tutorial and have one ambiguity. 
The tutorial is located here: 
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail
I'm on step one and cannot understand the following parts:

```
self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
```

This means that  chosenFolderId property will be observable?

```
<li data-bind="text: $data, 
               css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
               click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
```

I mean this specific expression:

```
click: $root.goToFolder
```

What pass this expression to goToFolder method? It seems that pass to function 
selected string from array but on first view it pass li object.

I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [knockout docs say](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function) the click binding will pass the data-context to the click handler function `goToFolder`.

In this case the data context is a string, the folder name because the click binding is inside a foreach binding.

This binding `click: $root.goToFolder` is basically shorthand for this:

```
click: function() { $root.goToFolder($data); }
```